# Swift compiler optimization of 'for' loops

Tags: swift, for-loop

I have a 'for' loop similar to this:

```
for i in 0...n - 1 {
    // do stuff, n is not changed
}
```

Back in the day, when I coded in FORTRAN, I was taught that this was a very inefficient way to code large 'for' loops.

Does the Swift compiler recognize the non-changing limit and pre-calculate n - 1?

Comment: It is quite easy to find out: Replace `n` by some function `n()` and check how often the function is called ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is yes.

`1...n - 1` represents a `Range` object. It is a literal of `Range`. Therefore, when compilation reaches the loop and sees the literal, it thinks

> It seems like that you want to create a new `Range<Int>` object! Here you go! Hmm... So I guess `i` is of type `Int`...

and so on.

This means that `n - 1` is evaluated when you create the object. And it stays that way, not evaluating it a second time. This code proves it by not printing only one hello:

```
var n = 10
for i in 1...n - 1 {
    n = 2
    print("Hello")
}
```

So yeah.

Note:

- It's better to use `1..<n` instead of `1...n - 1` in this case, they are the same.
- Apple actually recommends you to use this approach instead of the C-style for loop.
- The C-style for loop will be removed in Swift 3

Comment: It *is* better to use `0..<n`, but *why*?

Comment: It's my opinion... More swiftier, uses fewer characters, and not unclear. @MartinR

Comment: If `n == 0` then `0 ... n-1` aborts with a runtime exception, but `0 ..< n` doesn't (and executes the loop body zero times).

Comment: Some nitpicking: `1...n - 1` is not a *literal*. It is the result of the `...` operator applied to the integer literal `1` and the expression `n-1`.

Comment: Thanks all. I like the <n approach.